# How to form an object with the number of emails out of an array?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Implement and export by default a function that accepts a list of emails as input, and returns the number of emails located on each free domain. The list of free domains is stored in the constant freeEmailDomains.

```
    const emails = [
    'info@gmail.com',
    'info@yandex.ru',
    'info@hotmail.com',
    'mk@host.com',
    'support@hexlet.io',
    'key@yandex.ru',
    'sergey@gmail.com',
    'vovan@gmail.com',
    'vovan@hotmail.com',
];

const freeEmailDomains = ['gmail.com', 'yandex.ru'];

getFreeDomainsCount(emails);
// {
//   'gmail.com': 3,
//   'yandex.ru': 2,
//   'hotmail.com': 2,
// };
```

This is my code; what I have managed to code actually. I need to use high-order functions such as filter, map or reduce. And I can`t figure out how to form an object with the number of emails.

```
const getFreeDomainsCount = (emails) => {

  emails.filter((item) => item.includes('gmail.com') ||         
    item.includes('yandex.ru'));

  emails.map((item) => {item.split('@')});

  /*emails.reduce ((acc, item) => {
    let [,a] = item;
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty([,a])) {
   acc[[,a]] += 1;
    } else {
      acc[[,a]] = 1;
      }
    return acc
  }, {})
*/
};

console.log (getFreeDomainsCount(emails));
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const emails = [
    'info@gmail.com',
    'info@yandex.ru',
    'info@hotmail.com',
    'mk@host.com',
    'support@hexlet.io',
    'key@yandex.ru',
    'sergey@gmail.com',
    'vovan@gmail.com',
    'vovan@hotmail.com'
];

const freeEmailDomains = ['gmail.com', 'yandex.ru'];

const getFree = (emails) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    freeEmailDomains.map(d => [d, emails.filter(e => e.endsWith("@" + d)).length])
  )
}

console.log(getFree(emails));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this produces the output you're looking for, and it uses high order functions such as `reduce` and `filter`.

```js
const emails = [
    'info@gmail.com',
    'info@yandex.ru',
    'info@hotmail.com',
    'mk@host.com',
    'support@hexlet.io',
    'key@yandex.ru',
    'sergey@gmail.com',
    'vovan@gmail.com',
    'vovan@hotmail.com'
];

const freeEmailDomains = ['gmail.com', 'yandex.ru'];

function getFreeEmails(emails) {
    return emails.reduce((acc, email) => {
        const domain = email.split('@')[1];
        if (freeEmailDomains.includes(domain)) {
            acc[domain] = (acc[domain] || 0) + 1;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

I did some further optimization of my function and hopefully it's more efficient.

Comment: This is great and does answer OP's question. We should ideally try to reduce the number of passes through the array. Also, this line makes the complexity of the solution to `O(M x N)` where `M` is size of `emails` and `N` is size of `freeEmailDomains`. Can we optimize it?

Comment: Looks like GrafiCode posted a better solution!

Comment: @EthanR James' solution is even better

Comment: @GrafiCode I tried to make some extra optimizations and according to my NodeJS experiment, James' took 65,500ns to complete and this function took 64,900. Small optimization but it's something!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.map` and `Array.filter`

```js
const emails = [
  'info@gmail.com',
  'info@yandex.ru',
  'info@hotmail.com',
  'mk@host.com',
  'support@hexlet.io',
  'key@yandex.ru',
  'sergey@gmail.com',
  'vovan@gmail.com',
  'vovan@hotmail.com',
];

const freeEmailDomains = ['gmail.com', 'yandex.ru'];

console.log(freeEmailDomains.map(f => {
  return { [f]: emails.filter(e => e.includes(f)).length }
}))
```